# SQL express deployment on multiuser?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a application for a small user group and decided to use sql express.

So the design as normal is sql express will be hosted in one machine(as server machine) and users client app will connect to sql-express host machine for accessing db.

Now the problem is remote clients are not able to connect the db, but host machine can access the db. Can someone please help if you have tried this before ??

Connection string used is as below, do we need to change the connection string ?
Data Source=Hostname\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf;User Instance=true;

Note: Users are not domain connected they are LAN connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database service is probably not setup to listen on TCP port 1433 by default for security reasons. You need to use the configuration utility to enable remote access. You also need to make sure that port is not being blocked by a firewall. These [instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277) for SQL Server 2005 are useful.

If the users are not running under a domain account I believe you will have issues with authentication. You may want to add them to a domain, or enable SQL Server (password) authentication. After enabling this you can specify a username and password via the connection string. You need to make sure that the user exists and has access to the appropriate tables, views, or stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Server does not permit remote connections. You need to change this via the Server Configuration Manager in the Start Menu.